# Chain rule for multivariable functions confusion. General formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I'm struggling to work out what is what in the formula for the chain rule in general.
Say we have $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y)).$ And then we have $g(x,y)=(p(x,y),q(x,y))$.
So $(f \circ g)(x,y)=u(p(x,y),q(x,y)),v(p(x,y),q(x,y)).$
What is the formula for $\frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial x} $?
I can't seem to get it to make any sense.

Comment: In my opinion, it would help to write $f(s,t) = (u(s,t),v(s,t))$ and then you will have $s=p(x,y)$ and $t=q(x,y)$ and you can keep your letters (for partial derivatives) straight. Otherwise, it's just too confusing if you don't have derivative matrices to multiply.

Answer (score 1):

You have the chain
$$
(x,y)\to (p(x,y), q(x,y))\to (u(p(x,y),q(x,y)), v(p(x,y),q(x,y)).
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial x}=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial q}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}\right),
$$
where the derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ etc. are evaluated at $(p(x,y), q(x,y))$.

It is easier to use the matrix language and multiply the corresponding Jacobian matrices.